# What is a bowed rotor?

Tags: airbus-a320

I was going through A320 FCOM and came across this term. Is bowed rotor bending if the spool due to unequal thermal cooling

Comment: Maybe if we had some context...?

Comment: I believe he may read it from here https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84444/679